# node.js recursion routine in async call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion, nlp, wordnet

I have a resource that is very similar to the [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), where I can retrieve the a of synonyms of a given word. The goal is given a seed word, for example "car", I want to retrieve all possible transitive synonyms, for example, in the first call I get the synonyms of "car", which is "auto", "motocar", then I retrieve all the synonyms of "auto", and "motocar" and etc. Obviously the fechting is a recursive process, and retrieving synonyms is performed in async call

```
loadSynonyms("car", [], function(err, res) {
  console.log(res)
});

function loadResultSynonyms(synonyms, results, callback2) {

  async.series([
    function(callback) {
      async.eachSeries(results, function(res, callbackDone) {
        if (synonyms.indexOf(res) == -1) {
          synonyms.push(res)
          redisfetch(res, function(err, results) {
            loadSynonyms(synonyms, results)
            callbackDone();
          });
        } else {
          callbackDone();
        }
      })
    },

    function(callback) {
      callback2(null, synonyms)
    }
  ])
}
```

So, here I expect that at the end `synonyms` list will contain all synonyms, but it doesn't work. I think I messed up with recursion and async calls.

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Is it too obvious that your function is called `loadResultSynonyms` but you call `loadSynonyms`. I'm guessing that is a typo, so can you edit your question to fix it, if so.